# How to find values in specific format including parenthesis using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I have long string S, and I want to find value (numeric) in the following format "Value(**)", where ** is values I want to extract.

For example, S is `"abcdef Value(34) Value(56) Value(13)"`, then I want to extract values 34, 56, 13 from S.

I tried to use regex as follows.

```
import re
regex = re.compile('\Value(.*'))
re.findall(regex, S)
```

But the code yields the result I did not expect.

**Edit.** I edited some mistakes.

Comment: Only one of those values is preceded by `Value`. And your regex is looking for `Values`, not `Value` And parentheses in regex need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape the parentheses, correct the typo of `Value` (as opposed to `Values`), use a lazy repeater `*?` instead of `*`, add the missing right parenthesis, and capture what's enclosed in the escaped parentheses with a pair of parentheses:

```
regex = re.compile(r'Value\((.*?)\)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one of your numbers follows the word 'Value', so you can extract anything inside parentheses. You also need to escape the parentheses which are special characters.

```
regex = re.compile('\(.*?\)')
re.findall(regex, S)
```

Output:

> ['(34)', '(56)', '(13)']

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a capturing group that can return multiple matches. This string is: `(\(\d{2}\))?`. `\d` matches an digit and `{2}` matches exactly 2 digits. `{1,2}` will match 1 or 2 digits ect. `?` matches 0 to unlimited number of times. Each group can be indexed and combined into a list. This is a simple implementation and will return the numbers within parentheses.
eg. 'asdasd Value(102222), fgdf(20), he(77)' will match 20 and 77 but not 102222.